# Calculatiing ending coordinates given distance and x and y ratios on coordinate plane?

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I am working on a project in Java that describes a car driving a given distance. The function drive has three parameters: one for the distance traveled, one for the x ratio, and one for the y ratio. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INx3r.png) is the description of the function

Here is what I have of the drive function so far. I have the c variable because I had a thought about using the Pythagorean therom, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

```
public double drive(int distance, double xRatio, double yRatio)
{
    double disTraveled = 0.00;
    boolean empty = false;

    double c = 0.00;

    c = Math.sqrt((xRatio * xRatio) + (yRatio * yRatio));

    for( int i = 0; i < distance && empty == false; i++ )
    {
        if( gasTank.getLevel() == 0 )
        {
                System.out.printf("Ran out gas after driving %.2f miles\n", disTraveled);
                empty = true;
        }
        else
        {


            /*xCoord += xRatio;
            yCoord += yRatio;

            gasTank.setLevel(gasTank.getLevel() - (1.00 / engine.getMpg()));

            disTraveled ++;*/
        }
    }

    return disTraveled;
}
```

I am having trouble with the algorithm I need to use in order to find the final coordinates. What can I do find the ending point?

Comment: What work has been done so far to find the final coordinates?

Comment: Calculate the length of the hypotenuse of the triangle described by `x` and `y` (there's a method in `java.lang.Math` for that, if you don't know another way). Call that `r`. Then it's just `finalx = x * distance / r`, similarly for `y`.

Comment: Please include the code you have so far **in the question itself**. Do not post a screenshot or picture of your code. When you do include your code, please format the code appropriately by selecting the code you have pasted, then use the code formatting button (`{}`).

Answer (score 0):

## Step 1

Write down your known quantities. This should include your angle, distance and reference coordinates. For example:

```
Angle: 37 degrees Distance: 27 feet Starting point: x0 = 3; y0 = 5
```

## Step 2

Calculate the cosine of the angle and multiply this by the distance.

```
cos(37) = 0.7986 27 * 0.7986 = 21.563
```

## Step 3

Calculate the sine of the angle and multiply this by the distance.

```
sin(37) = 0.6018 27 * 0.6018 = 16.249
```

## Step 4

Add the cosine result to the x-coordinate from the starting point and add the sine result to the y-coordinate to get the coordinates for the second point.

`x1 = x0 + 21.563 = 3 + 21.563 = 24.563`

```
y1 = y0 + 16.249 = 5 + 16.249 = 21.249
```

## Notice

Calculate the angle from your x/y coords.

Writing this as Java code shouldn‘t be too hard. Have a look at 
[Java.Math](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)

Comment: Don't involve angles unless it is necessary. It decreases performance by quite a bit and possibly introduces ambiguities. The same thing can be done much cheaper by normalizing the direction vector. Btw, this answer is incomplete without instructions on how to calculate the angle (if OP knows how to calculate the angle, he will probably also know how to do the remaining steps).